# How to change canvas size in fireworks without your work being moved?

Tags: adobe-fireworks, mockup, canvas

I am making a website mockup in adobe fire works. I noticed that i need more space so i try to change the canvas size vertically and it does add more space but i notice that my content is moved out of place for some reason. Anyone know how i can prevent my content from moving and still add more canvas size space vertically?

Answer (score 1):

Well this is not supposed to happen and I've never seen that happening. But there is a workaround that might help. Draw a shape (for example a rectangle) that is bigger than the canvas. Make it size and position it as you want your new canvas to be, and then press `Fit Canvas` on the Properties panel (no objects should be selected to see that button). Now you can delete the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

When you go to do this, there should be a 3x3 arrangement of little boxes to describe how your content is positioned within the new space. Default has it in the middle, you probably want top.